# Как добавить слеш к ссылке? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Привет,

Поставили плагин от гугл AMP (тема на Вордпрессе). Он в хеде добавляет такую ссылку `<link rel="amphtml" href="http://сайт.com/amp" />`

Вопрос: как в конец добавить слеш? Должно выйти `<link rel="amphtml" href="http://сайт.com/amp/" />`

Спасибо.

Comment: Какой плагин установлен конкретно? Их там несколько в репозитории. Дайте ссылку.

Comment: Если имеется ввиду вот этот плагин https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/amp/ то он устанавливает ссылку со слеш на конце. Ошибка у вас в другом месте.

Comment: Да плагин вы указали верно. В урле он правильно раболтает и добавляет слеш.

Comment: А вот в хеде сайте прописывает так <link rel="amphtml" href="http://сайт.com/amp" />

Comment: Посмотрите на моем тестовом сайте: http://test.kagg.eu/3/

Comment: А самое интересное, что это вообще не нужно - WP сам добавляет слеш в конце. http://test.kagg.eu/3/amp перейдите по этой ссылке без слеш. У вас проблема не в плагине.

Comment: Спасибо - буду разбираться

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не в плагине, он добавляет слеш в конец корректно (если у вас правильная структура постоянных ссылок со слеш на конце).

Можно добавить такой фильтр в functions.php:

```
function my_amp_get_permalink( $amp_url, $post_id ) {
    return trailingslashit( $amp_url );
}

add_filter( 'amp_get_permalink', 'my_amp_get_permalink', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: спасибо за фильтр, но в моем случае не помогает(( везде слеши добавляются как нужно, все работает норм. А эта ссылка без слеша. у вас на сайте было все норм. Скорее действительно что то не верно у меня, а не в плагине. стараюсь найти в чем причина.

Comment: Ищите в структуре постоянных ссылок